# How can I retrive the different data from the 2 csv files in shell script

Tags: shell

please help me
I tried for retrieving the same data
I am facing problem with the retrieving the different data

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Also, as this is not a free coding service, we'd appreciate seeing some attempt first. 
Thanks.

Comment: What is the meaning of _retrieving different data_ and _retrieving the same data_. Are you **seriously** believing that someone can post an answer with a question formulated in this way?